# paginationPageSizeSelector In ag grid is not working

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want to display page size drop-down in my angular ag grid and found that we can do this by using

[paginationPageSizeSelector] = “[10, 20, 50, 100]

But if I add this in my ag-grid, it is throwing an error as below

```
Can’t bind to‘paginationPageSizeSelector’ since it isn’t a known property of ‘ag-grid-angular’
```

I am using ag-grid-angular version 30.0.6

Please anybody help me to display page size drop-down for my ag-grid

Html:

```
<ag-grid-angular
[pagination]="true"
[paginationPageSize]=10
[paginationPageSizeSelector]="paginationPageSizeSelector"
/* other grid options ... */>
```

Typescript

```
paginationPageSizeSelector = [10, 20, 50, 100];
```

Comment: please share the code and the html, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: When this kind error appears it's generally because we forgot import any Module, revisite [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-pagination/#example-customising-pagination) to know if it's the reason